# Function is calling repeatedly in when calling in ng-src image

Tags: angularjs, html

I've some thing like this

```
<img width="100" height="177" ng-show="{{fileName}}" ng-src="{{getPath(fileName) || '' }}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="test" onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')">
```

In Controller,

```
 $scope.getPath = function (fileName) {

    if (fileName !== '' || fileName !== null || fileName !== undefined) {
        var random = (new Date()).getTime();
        var fillName = "/data/my uploads/" + fileName + "?v=" + random;
        return fillName;
    }
    else {
        return "//:0";
    }
```

In html5

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>
        <img width="100" height="177" ng-show="{{item.fileName}}" ng-src="{{getPath(item.fileName) || '' }}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="test"
         onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Problem**: The `getPath` function is calling repeatedly and not stopping. How to stop that?

```
INFO  2015-10-02 01:11:29-63579388289280629312 - Request: GET http://localhost:26264/data/uploads/my shop/my branch/null?v=1443771685319

INFO  2015-10-02 01:11:29-63579388289280629312 - Response: GET http://localhost:26264/data/uploads/my shop/my branch/null?v=1443771685319
```

Comment: don't wrap function calls inside expressions, they will be called and evaluated every `$digest`, and a single change can cause multiple `$digest` cycles.

Comment: basically, every time the digest runs, your function is generating a new link for the image.

Comment: @Claies if i remove {{}} the getPath function is not calling. Ex: -show="item.fileName" ng-src="getPath(item.fileName) || '' "

Comment: I never said to remove the expression, I suggested that calling the function in this context is a bad idea, and is what is causing your problem.  Update the path on the object in the controller, don't update it from the view.

Comment: I assume you are fetching the items filename in the controller and saving them in $scope.item.filename, why not at the same time around store the src in $scope.item.src ? That way you handle the data exchange in the controller and only using the view for its purpose: "displaying data"

Comment: @CarstenFarving, Same i am doing. thanks

Comment: Solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911718/img-ng-src-image-is-never-ending.

Comment: so basically after asking the question a second time, you figured out that the problem wasn't even with the `getPath` function at all?  It was actually a JQuery call in `onerror` which is unrelated to angular completely?

Comment: @Claies, Yes true. Because i didn't get good solution here. None of them told me about onerror is the problem. But why down voted?

Answer (score 2):

Accept the fact that the function will be called many times and put only light operations in it.

In your case you don't need to refresh the path every call, you can instead store it after the first call, and then get the stored value on subsequent calls.

```
$scope.getPath = function (item) { // change this to item, so you can store the result
    if (item.fillName) return item.fillName; // subsequent calls after the first one go here

    // only the first one goes here
    if (item.fileName !== '' || item.fileName !== null || item.fileName !== undefined) {
        var random = (new Date()).getTime();
        item.fillName = "/data/my uploads/" + item.fileName + "?v=" + random; // store result
    }
    else {
        item.fillName = "//:0";
    }

    return item.fillName;
}
```

PS: It is normal to have functions that run on every digest, like `ng-show`, just try to make them light and return fast.

Comment: Any alternative for this "if (item.fileName !== '' || item.fileName !== null || item.fileName !== undefined)" looks too long :)

Comment: do `var fileName = item.fileName` if you like, I would just use `if (item.fileName)`

Comment: Above code works fine. after adding that i am getting this 

INFO  2015-10-02 03:02:40-6357939496072691129 - Request: GET http://localhost:26264/undefined

INFO  2015-10-02 03:02:40-6357939496072691129 - Response: GET http://localhost:26264/undefined
Not Found
INFO  2015-10-02 03:02:40-6357939496074282039 - Request: GET http://localhost:26264/undefined

INFO  2015-10-02 03:02:40-6357939496074282039 - Response: GET http://localhost:26264/undefined

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need your interpolation expression inside Angular's directives.

Change to:

```
<img width="100" height="177" ng-show="item.fileName" ng-src="getPath(item.fileName) || '' " class="img-thumbnail" alt="test"
         onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')">
```

As @Claies said if you do that they will be evaluated n every digest cycle.

Comment: if i remove {{}} the getPath function is not calling. Ex: -show="item.fileName" ng-src="getPath(item.fileName) || '' "