# img ng-src image is never ending

Tags: angularjs, html

I've something like below

```
<img width="100" height="177" ng-show="file.fileName" ng-src="file.fullPath" class="img-thumbnail" alt="test" onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')">

fileName is "abc.png"
fullPath is "/data/uploads/abc.png"
```

But, The src is never ending.. below is the log.

```
INFO 2015-10-02 03:02:40-6357939496072691129 - Request: GET localhost:26264/undefined 
INFO 2015-10-02 03:02:40-6357939496072691129 - Response: GET localhost:26264/undefined Not Found 
INFO 2015-10-02 03:02:40-6357939496074282039 - Request: GET localhost:26264/undefined 
INFO 2015-10-02 03:02:40-6357939496074282039 - Response: GET localhost:26264/undefined
```

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img width="100" height="177" ng-show="file.fileName" ng-src="file.fullPath" class="img-thumbnail" alt="test" onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')">
```

Your `onerror` sets the src to the attribute `altSrc`, but since you haven't defined `altSrc` it errors out again and causes the loop.

To prevent the loop, define an `altSrc`. To prevent this in general, don't inline javascript like this. Instead define a background image for your image element in CSS. That way you don't ever need to check for image errors, since the loaded image will simply cover the CSS background image.

Comment: Great solution. Accepted.